# Syncing two rows from different tables in the same MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table named `clients`, in that table there's two columns of importance; `id` and `client`. I have a secondary table in the same database named `calendar`. I really want the two columns of `id` and `client` in the `calendar` table to sync with the ones in `client` table.

Right now I am using this PHP to execute this in MySQL:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO calendar (id, client) SELECT id, client FROM clients;
```

Is there a better way of accomplish this task? Maybe a built in function in MySQL that I have overlooked or something like that?

Comment: Assuming you have a unique key on `(id, client)` that should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Triggers : The MySQL trigger is a database object that is associated with a table. It will be activated when a defined action is executed for the table.

The trigger can be executed when you run one of the following MySQL statements on the table: INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE and it can be invoked before or after the event.

You can make trigger when you insert or update a row in main table and make the changes in another table

Example:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER my_sync_trigger 
AFTER INSERT ON `clients` for each row
begin
INSERT INTO calender (id,client)
Values (new.id, new.client);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**"new" stands for the new value inserted into clients table. The same value will be inserted into id and client column in calender.**

Note: **single quotes are removed from table name** because quotes effectively make it a string literal instead of a proper identifier. 
DELIMITER command will change the ending of each statement from ";" to "$$" so that MySQL is not confused with ";" inside and outside the trigger

Make similar triggers for update and delete also

Simple guide for examples and syntax:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I am not well versed on MySQL at all so I am having a bit of a hard time following that guide, could you by any chance give me an example using the scenario I provided?

Comment: @Tony I have updated the answer with an example and a link to easier tutorial on Triggers

Comment: That works (calendar is spelled incorrectly though, which confused me). But how could I make it update on edits as well?

Comment: Create another trigger that says - After Update On <Table Name>. It will be better if you go through the tutorial because it is very hard to explain everything on stackoverflow. Triggers are solution to your problem, so go ahead and enquire more about them :)